# what dose socket.INADDR_* do

Tags: python, python-3.x, idl-programming-language

I have an issue  with  socket.INADDR_* constant of Python socket 
I cant understand what dose these constants do? For example:

```
socket.INADDR_LOOPBAD
socket.INADDR_RESERVED
```

What does the above options do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those constants refer to [IP addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address). Refer to your system Unix documentation for what they mean, as indicated in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.SOMAXCONN). I don't think `socket.INADDR_LOOPBAD` or `socket.INADDR_RESERVED` are real constants.

A few common constants are:

- `INADDR_LOOPBACK` (127.0.0.1) - your local host, via a special network device known as the loopback device
- `INADDR_ANY` (0.0.0.0) - any address used for binding (accept connections to any IP on the machine)

The [IP manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html) has more useful information on these constants.